# Intellij (Android studio) member variable prefix

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, android-studio

How do I configure Android Studio (or Intellij generally) to correctly generate getters and setters for member variables with prefixes?

If I have a class

```
public class Foo{
    int mBar;
}
```

I want it to create `getBar()` instead of `getMBar` when I do `Refactor->Encapsulate` or `Generate`

**EDIT**

I found the way to do it per-project basis: You just go `File->Settings->Project Settings->Code Style`

But it created a settings file somewhere in my project directory.

I want a solution which allows me to do it once for all projects, present and future.

Comment: Why not use standard naming conventions, using readable code, and name your field `bar`? Anyway, use Project Settings - Code Style - Java - Code Generation

Comment: This convention is adopted in all the Android projects I work with. Besides, I think it is quite a "standard" in Android community, afaik.

Comment: You're right: https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html. Disgusting, and in contradiction with Java standard conventions, even the standard Google ones: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.5-non-constant-field-names

Comment: Instead of Project Settings, use Default Settings.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In Mac OS

- Android Studio -> Preferences -> Code Style -> Java
- on the right panel, click on the right arrow until you see `code generation tab`
- Click ok

[image]

Answer (score 69):

Try going to File-->Other Settings-->Default Settings. Your should be able to make prefixes for every other project that you do if you change prefix settings with the scheme set to default instead of Project. The prefix change would be in Java and Code Generation. That will fix setters and getters.

Comment: Thanks! The logic behind introducing an "Other Settings" screen really doesn't make any sense, as one would expect setting the default scheme through Settings would suffice. I really don't understand that rationale in Android Studio.

Comment: Ah, I sort of see now. The underlying problem is that you cannot change the default settings. Any sort of change creates a copy, which you cannot rename either. I've only found that saving "Default" as something else (i.e. "The real default") through the Code Style Schemes dialog provides a way of managing settings across projects in any sort of meaningful way. Unfortunately, Android Studio will default back to "Default", which again, is read-only.

Comment: Am I able to set a couple of prefixes?

Answer (score 17):

In AS 2.2.1:

File > Settings > Editor > Code Style> Java > Code Generation > Naming > Name Prefix Field / Name Prefix Static Field

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Android Studio's preferences (from the Android Studio menu on Mac and from **File** -> **Settings** on Windows and Linux).
2. Expand **Editor** and then expand **Code Style**.
3. Select **Java**, then choose the **Code Generation** tab.
4. In the **Naming** table, select the **Field** row and add `m` as the name prefix for `fields`. Then add `s` as the name prefix for `static` fields.

[image: Code Generation Setting in Android Studio 3.x]

5. Click **Ok**

Answer (score 0):

You need go to **Setting** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Java** and just specify **s-prefix** in **static field**, then click **OK**

[image]