# Member variable prefix ("m") in getters and setters in Android studio 1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I configure Android Studio "v 1.1" to correctly generate getters and setters for member variables with prefixes and not to generate getters like: `getmName()` and instead generate `getName()`?

I've looked at many questions like : [Intellij (Android studio) member variable prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732722/intellij-android-studio-member-variable-prefix), but it seems to be removed in "Version 1.1"

Am i right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in `preferences -> code style -> java` you'll find the tab *code generation*. There you will find a matrix of text box, where you can define prefix and suffix for field, static field, parameter and local variable. Enter `m` for the pair (*Name Prefix, Field*) and it should work

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Editor->Code Style->Java, then last tab *'Code Generation'*

write **m** in field's *'Name Prefix'* column.

Answer (score -2):

You must to use names without 'm' in start all private values.

http://jakewharton.com/just-say-no-to-hungarian-notation/