# Member variable prefix (“m”) in getters and setters in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070139/member-variable-prefix-m-in-getters-and-setters-in-android-studio-1-1), I want to specify that my fields start with `m` and when I use Source Action > Generate Getters and Setters in Visual Studio Code, I want it to recognize that fields start with an `m`. I can not find this setting in vscode or the java extensions. Is this possible?

For example, a field of `private int mDistance` would generate `getmDistance()`, but I want `getDistance()`

Comment: Just as a heads-up: this convention is fairly rare in the Java world (not entirely unheard of, but the majority of coding conventions that I've worked with avoid such prefixes). That is likely one of the reason why not every tool has good support for it.

Comment: If you use Lombok to generate them instead of generating them as source (much nicer since you don't then have them cluttering up your source code), you can specify the prefix to the [`@Getter` and `@Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) annotations or the [`@Accessors`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) annotation.

Comment: for example: `private int mage; public int getMage() { return mage; }` this is getter function generated in vscode-java. what's your wanted function name style? can you give  a example?

Comment: @MollyWang I'm talking about if I have a field like `private int mDistance;`, I'd want `getDistance()`, `setDistance()`

Comment: Sorry to tell you that there's no such settings in vscode-java, but you can put a feature request about customize getters and setter function in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md&title=Feature+request) for production group to have a look at.