# Format Java and prefix fields with 'm'

Tags: java, android-studio, formatting

I work with Intellij in Android Studio. I got a project where part of the developers prefix the fields with 'm' and part not.

How can I format the code to apply the 'm' prefix format on all the fields.

P.S
I hate this formatting, but we agree to use it.

Comment: Better to agree on one standard. M prefix is an old C/C++ that should be discarded.

Comment: @duffymo I agree, but now I just looking for a solution to convert the code to one format automatically.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and fight stupidity harder.

Comment: I'd suggest regular expressions, but then you have to refactor all the variable's access methods too so it probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Android Studio -> Preferences -> Code Style -> Java
> - on the right panel, click on the right arrow until you see `code generation tab`
> - Click ok
>
> [image]

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228793/57490

Comment: it's not perfect as you can't change formating, but it help with the new generated fields, so I accept it for now.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman If you set the prefix setting, then go to rename a variable in the IDE, it will autosuggest the "m" prefix in the list of suggestions.